# How to Play and loop all videos in folder by JavaFX Media Player?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm) tutorial.Here shows only one video playing.
My requirement is like this,
I have several videos in folder("application path/videos")

I want to run this all videos one by one, and continuously run all videos (looping)

another think is when i add new videos to that folder,I want to add that video for playing list.

Comment: Use the `onEndOfMedia` method. You can pass a runnable that will be executed once the media has reached the end playback, i.e. the `stopTime`.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for play multiple video files

Comment: I'm at work at the moment, but I'll try and throw something together when I get home (about 4 hours)

Comment: Any one have sample code for that???

Comment: Check the selected answer in the duplicate question-- there is a link to some src code which should help you.